# Spring Data Rest Wrongly Detects findAll() As A Search Method

Tags: spring-data-rest

I extend CrudRepository so I can add `@Query` and method security annotations such as `@PreAuthorize` etc to the methods `findAll`, `findById`, `save` and `delete`. When I do this, the `findAll` method appears as `/<REPO>/search/findAll`:

```
    public interface PricingPlanRepo extends CrudRepository<PricingPlan, UUID> {
    
        @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasAnyScopeFor('pricingplan', 'read')")
        @Query("SELECT e FROM #{#entityName} e WHERE e.tenant IN ?#{security.getTenants('pricingplan', 'r')} OR '*' IN ?#{security.getTenants('pricingplan', 'r')}")
        @Override
        Iterable<PricingPlan> findAll();
```

```
$ curl http://localhost:8084/pricingPlans/search
{
  "_links" : {
    "findAll" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8084/pricingPlans/search/findAll"
    },
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8084/pricingPlans/search"
    }
  }
}
```

Other repositories in which I don't mention `findAll` don't have that search endpoint. Is this a bug? How can I get around that?

Answer (score 0):

According to Spring Data REST [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.hiding-repositories), to hide query methods, annotate your method with `@RestResource(exported = false)`.

```java
public interface PricingPlanRepo extends CrudRepository<PricingPlan, UUID> {  

    @RestResource(exported = false)
    @Override
    Iterable<PricingPlan> findAll();
}
```

Comment: Sure, but that will remove `GET /pricingPlans` as a REST call. I only want to get rid of `GET /pricingPlans/search/findAll` which apparently maps to the same `findAll` method in the repository.